# Docker, Django, Gunicorn, Nginx, and a 502 bad gateway error

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I am relatively new to Docker and have run into a problem that I can't seem to find a solution for. I have two Docker stacks that are running Nginx and Django however, one of the stacks is reachable via web browser, and the other times out with a bad gateway error. Both stacks are running on the same server but on different ports, the stack that runs on port 8000 is reachable the stack that runs on 8010 throws the 502 error. I have verified that the ports are open on the host and that I can ping from the Nginx container to the Django container. I have also spun up each stack separately which ended with the same results. I am running out of ideas so, any insight would be appreciated.

Server: VM - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)

Docker version 20.10.3, build 48d30b5

**Working Docker-compose file**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations &&
                    python manage.py migrate &&
                    gunicorn laitteiden_saatavuus.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
    expose:
      - 8000
      - 1433
    env_file:
      - ./laitteiden_saatavuus/.env
    networks:
      - database
      - nginx_network
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./laitteiden_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/laitteiden_db.sql
    networks:
      - database
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    networks:
      - nginx_network
    depends_on:
      - web

networks:
  database:
    driver: bridge
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
```

**Working Nginx conf**

```
upstream laitteiden_saatavuus {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://laitteiden_saatavuus;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/web/static/;
    }

}
```

**Non working docker-compose file**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "gunicorn eq_allocation.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/equipment_drill/web/static
    expose:
      - 8000
      - 1433
    env_file:
      - ./eq_allocation/.env
    networks:
      - eq_network

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/equipment_drill/web/static
    ports:
      - 8010:80
    networks:
      - eq_network
    depends_on:
      - web

networks:
  eq_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

**Non working Nginx conf**

```
upstream eq_allocation {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://eq_allocation;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/equipment_drill/web/static/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `web` service container starts successfully and has an `Up` status in the `docker ps` output?

Comment: Yes, all containers have an UP status.

Comment: Try exposing the Django server directly without the nginx. Also check django container logs

Comment: I exposed the Gunicorn/Django server however, I am still not able to connect. However, I am able to connect if I run python manage runserver from the command line. The container logs have a number of WORKER TIMEOUTs from Gunicorn but nothing else.

Comment: What if you run the gunicorn from command line? It should either log a request or some kind of error... If runserver works there should be something with the gunicorn however there are hardly any place for the mistake...

Comment: When running Gunicorn from the command line I get this error django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect)') which is strange. Its the first time I have seen this error.

Comment: That looks like a possible culprit